# Different action menu items for each fragment with same navigation drawer in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-menu

I have a Main activity that hosts a navigation drawer and multiple fragments. Each fragment has its own set of menu items.

Now the problem starts when I add the **onOptionsItemSelected** method, the navigation Drawer won't open. And when I don't add the **onOptionsItemSelected** method, navigation Drawer opens but then menu items are not working.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment_type_data_stats, parent, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_payment_type_stats, menu);
    Objects.requireNonNull(((MainActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("title");
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_today:
            getDataForToday();
            break;
        case R.id.action_past_seven:
            getDataForPeriod(calendarDates.pastSeventhDate(), calendarDates.todayDate());
            break;
        case R.id.action_custom_date:
            openDatePickerDialog(sdf);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you have any suggestions for fixing this problem, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- MainActivity changes:

All you have to do is change ***onOptionsItemSelected*** in MainActivity from

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
```

and change it to

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  //important
    }
```

As far as the ***onCreateOptionsMenu*** method in MainActivity, you can leave it empty with just

```
return true
```

- Fragment changes

For fragment (each fragment can have separate action menu items) you need to implement 3 methods

- ***onCreateView***
- ***onCreateOptionsMenu***
- ***onOptionsItemSelected***

Example:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment_type_data_stats, parent, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);  //important
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        //each frag can have different menu
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_payment_type_stats, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_today:
                getDataForToday();
                break;
            case R.id.action_yesterday:
                getDataForPeriod(calendarDates.yesterdayDate(), calendarDates.yesterdayDate());
                break;
            case R.id.action_past_seven:
                getDataForPeriod(calendarDates.pastSeventhDate(), calendarDates.todayDate());
                break;
            case R.id.action_past_thirty:
                getDataForPeriod(calendarDates.pastThirtiethDate(), calendarDates.todayDate());
                break;
            case R.id.action_custom_date:
                openDatePickerDialog(sdf);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can set manually -

```
`drawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
     });`
```

or can try this
`mDrawerToggle.syncState();`

Comment: Unfortunately not working, still getting an empty click. It's very peculiar, when I remove the onOptionsItemSelected method for menu items drawer is working just fine.